# "Sun bleaching" of silver granules in B&W print

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

An image on a black & white print is the result of microscopic metallic silver granules contained in the emulsion.  If such a print is left in the sun, the dark areas will eventually fade due to "sun bleaching".

What physical process is occurring to the silver granules as a result of EM radiation flux, and what happens to reduce the darkness of the silver?  Or, is "sun bleaching" a result of something unrelated to the direct effects of EM radiation, such as heating causing a chemical change (in which case this question belongs on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/))?

Comment: I have to say I see nothing but articles about how to bleach, how to enhance your photos by bleaching, the complete opposite of you are asking.  They all seem to love bleaching. Imo,  I would definitely consider chemistrySE,  but first maybe someone here has an idea. Best of luck with it.

Comment: http://gawainweaver.com/images/uploads/Weaver_Guide_to_Gelatin_Silver.pdf suggests that light itself is not usually a problem, but heat can be.  That said, your description of "bleaching" doesn't exactly match the common issues that it lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best description I found was from [A Guide to Fiber-Base Gelatin Silver Print Condition and Deterioration by Gawain Weaver](http://gawainweaver.com/images/uploads/Weaver_Guide_to_Gelatin_Silver.pdf)

There it mentions that the dark color in the photograph is due to the excellent absorption of light by small ($0.5 \mu \text{m}$) aggregations of silver.  If these particles are modified in some way, the overall appearance changes.

> ...as prints decay, silver atoms can migrate away from the silver
>   particles, gradually creating many smaller silver particles in place
>   of the original filament. This causes a gradual warming of the image,
>   as well as fading, since the smaller particles appear more yellow and
>   sometimes cannot be seen at all.

and..

> The color of silver also changes when it reacts with chemicals in its
>   environment to form new compounds such as silver sulfide. This can
>   occur intentionally during toning, or over time, as the silver image
>   reacts with chemicals in the air, such as hydrogen sulfide. When this
>   process occurs over time, the silver grains tend to disperse into
>   smaller particles causing image fading.

The text further details multiple types of image damage and some of their effects.  It does note that light by itself isn't normally a problem, but temperature is.

> You may have noticed that light has not been included here as a
>   primary factor in image stability. Exposure to high levels of light
>   for extended periods may cause embrittlement of the paper support, and
>   the associated heat may speed image silver deterioration. However,
>   compared to the damage that light inflicts on most color prints or on
>   resin-coated gelatin silver prints, fiber-base gelatin silver prints
>   are quite stable with respect to light exposure.